# 3D Cursor and Resetting View in Quad View

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

I've been using quad view, and had an earlier issue ([Why does changing the 3D cursor move other quad view windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/why-does-changing-the-3d-cursor-move-other-quad-view-windows)) with a change in the 3D cursor in one viewport changing the views in the other 3 viewports. I understand I can get around this problem by disabling Lock to Cursor in the View panel, but this introduces another problem: What if I want Lock to Cursor enabled for my workflow; that is, I like to be able to rotate the camera around the cursor, but I don't want to fling the other three viewports away while I'm doing this in one viewport?

Another related question: In quad view, how do I reset one of the viewports to be centered on the coordinate axis? Sometimes this 3D cursor problem can send another viewport *very* far away, and it can be impossible to recenter the view by hand, because one does not know which way to drag the view.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Properties* panel on the right (press <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle) you have the option to change the location of your 3D cursor.

If you are working in Quad view and want to center your cursor on this specific axis you can zoom out the regarding field:

- for the top/down view it would be the X and Y axis
- for the right/left view it would be the Z and Y axis
- for the front/back view it would be the Z and X axis

If you have viewport projection set to orthographic then depending on the angle you could also shift the location of the cursor.

If you click on the surface of an object the cursor will be placed right on top of it.